# sql Summarising table columns by e-mail

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (SQL) where customers can have different statuses. Each status is noted with a date in a separate column.

Currently, however, the customer record is not enriched with the new status including the time stamp. As soon as a customer receives a new status, it is entered in the table.

[image: 1]

Now I would like to merge these different timestamps of the individual customers into one row in a sql query and export it as a csv.

The email address serves as the identifier here.

How can I write the sql query so that I have the statuses of the customer abc@gmx.net in one row?

I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: The format for `timestamp` datatype is always `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Your example above illustrate a `date` datatype instead. When you said _"different timestamp"_, that includes same date with different time. It's not a big deal but I think you should always make sure your question description, query and data example matches and are using the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to join your table multiple times. here is an example fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca5f74/3

```
select t.email,t1.date1,t2.date2
from t 
inner join t as t1 on t.email = t1.email and t1.date1 is not null
inner join t as t2 on t.email = t2.email and t2.date2 is not null

group by t.email,t1.date1,t2.date2

email   date1   date2
a   1/1/2011    2/2/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select email, max(col1), max(col2)
from t
group by email;
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you make a lot of assumptions. Like: 1. Timestamps that are numeric. 2. There will only be one instance of an event. 3. The last instance of a particular event is important, not the first. None of these assumptions are clear from the question. That's not your fault, by the way.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware . . . Huh?  There is no assumption that timestamps are numeric.  The sample data has only one valid value in each column.  There is nothing about "last instance"; this just returns the one value from the column, which appears to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You cannot take a `max()` from a string like `"2021-03-03"`, it has to be numeric, and I agree that the sample data only has one valid value per column, but there's no garantee that will always be the case. As I said, your query might work if all the assumptions hold.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware . . . Not in any database that supports SQL.  `MAX()` works on pretty much all data types.  You might want to try it sometime.

Comment: The OP talks about timestamps, yet we see dates. If the type is `DATE` then `MAX()` will work, since it is numeric, but if the type is `VARCHAR` then it won't work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware . . . Try it out.  `MAX()` works just fine on strings.

Comment: Sorry, the @ thing doesn't work for some reason. Anyway, [I tested it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c522a/1/0) and it did indeed work. But in this case it probably relies on alfa-numeric sorting, not on numeric sorting. It doesn't matter in this case, but if the string were mm/dd/yyyy it wouldn't work?